# How do I stop the display when I click on the Chrome extension and have it display every time someone refresh their page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I refresh a new page, my quote doesn't show as intended.

Showing quote when clicked on button but I want it to [show when each page is refreshed or opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJNYC.png)

My manfest.js

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Mindfulness Quotes",
"description": "Mindfulness quotes",
"version": "10",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
 "activeTab"
 ]
}
```

Do I have to make changes to manifest.json file or another file?

Comment: Default_popup opens only on user gesture. You can show a notification instead.

Comment: Thank you! It is the over ride function that I needed to use.